# how to get the user's nickname if he has it?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

in the title of embed I want to show the name that the user is using on the server

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

  let user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author;
  
  let avatar = user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 });

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor(`#2f3136`) 
    .setTitle(`${user.username}`) 
    .setDescription(`Clique **[aqui](${avatar})** para baixar o avatar.`)
    .setImage(avatar);
 await message.channel.send(embed); 

};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildMember.displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) should help. This gets the nickname of the `GuildMember` and defaults to the username if there is no nickname. There is 1 other problem: you are getting a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). `User`s don't have `nickname`s or `displayName`s, because they are not connected to a guild. Define user like this instead:

```js
let user = message.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
```

Full code:

```js
let user = message.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
  
  let avatar = user.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 }) //get user from guildmember

  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor(`#2f3136`) 
    .setTitle(user.displayName}) 
    .setDescription(`Clique **[aqui](${avatar})** para baixar o avatar.`)
    .setImage(avatar);
 await message.channel.send(embed);
```